# Single User Application File/Data Storage Recommendations

Tags: database, linq, sqlite, linq-to-objects, protobuf-net

I currently have a C# winform application in which you enter data that is ultimately relational. The amount of data being stored isn't huge. The original version used SQL CE to store the information. However, I found it to be quite slow. Also, I wanted to be able to save application files using my own extension.

I had changed my approach to basically keep my data loaded in-memory using class objects. To save, I simply serialize everything using ProtoBuf and deserialize when opening a file. This approach is lightning fast and changes are never persisted until a user clicks save. However, I find it a little cumbersome to query my hierarchical data. I query data using Linq-To-Objects. I'll have ClassA having a GUID key. I can reference ClassA in ClassB via the GUID. However, I can't really do an easy SQL join-type query to get ClassB properties along with ClassA properties. I get around it by creating a navigation property on ClassB to ClassA that simple returns ClassA via a LINQ query on the GUID. However, this results in a lot of collection scanning.

What options are out there that give me fast, single-user, relational file storage? I would still like to work in-memory where changes aren't persisted until a user uses File|Save. I would also like to be able to continue querying the data using LINQ. I'm looking at SQLite as an option. Are there better options or approaches out there for me?

**UPDATE**

I was unaware of the AsReference option in the ProtoMember attribute `[ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]`. If I abandon foreign keys in my classes and simply reference the related objects, then it looks like I'm able to serialize and deserialize using ProtoBuf while keeping my object references. Thus, I can easily use Linq-To-Objects to query my objects. I need to stop thinking from the database side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all your objects in some sort of hierarchical structure, you can also store the exact same objects in other structures at an overhead of 4 bytes/object (32bit machines).

Assuming you have a base object like:

```
public class HierarchyElement
{
    public List<HierarchyElement> Children { get; set; }
    public HierarchyElement Parent { get; set; }
}
```

So you have the root element in a local variable, which via the Children property, and the Children property of those first children, etc etc store an unknown number of objects in a hierarchy.

However, while you are building that object, or after deserialising it, you can add a reference to each HierarchyElement to a List (or other flat structure of your choice).

You can then use this flat list to do your Linq queries against.

Comment: Looking further into Protobuf, it seems I can continue using it, but instead of "foreign-keying" using IDs, I can just reference the actual objects as you show here. The references will get serialized if I use the [ProtoMember(N, AsReference = true] attribute. I guess I had database table structuring stuck in my head.